# Updating UITableView cells according to the text entered in a text filed that is in the same main view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Is it possible to update the cells of a table according to the value entered in the text field which is in the same view or when clicking on a button which is in the same view. can this be done when all the components are in the same view? of course i know that i will have to use a cell and a table view an all in that view.

If it's possible please hint me to what method in the `TableView` Delegate I should work with to make this happen or if I have to write a custom method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Follow any example to create a simple UItableView. Just update tableView data source data and call [tableView reloadData] on button click.

Comment: @Piyuesh i did that and it worked, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into `UISearchController`

Links to explore:

- http://www.raywenderlich.com/16873/how-to-add-search-into-a-table-view
- http://jduff.github.io/2010/03/01/building-a-searchview-with-uisearchbar-and-uitableview/
- http://www.iphonedeveloperdiary.com/2010/07/adding-a-uisearchbar-to-top-part-tableview/
- http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/38913-slicks-uitableview-series.html
- https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

---

### OR...

If you want to do it using something like a simple `UITextField`, then in the `-textFieldShouldReturn`, you can use `NSPredicate` to create an array of *searched* objects and then simply can do a `[self.tableView reloadData]`.
*(just ensure that the datasource of your `tableView` is using this array*)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it just by using

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

On Clicking if button please ensure to update UITableView Datasource Array to update.

Comment: This was part of what i needed, thanks for your time.